# How to play AMR audio file on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, avaudioplayer, mpmovieplayer, amr

I have tried using `AVAudioPlayer` , `MPMoviePlayer` to play `AMR` files but unable to play them. `AVAudioPlayer` play method always returns `NO` for `AMR` files and `MPMoveiPlayer` post `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification` as soon as it is played. Even tried to play play `AMR` with webview but without success.

Is there any other way to play `AMR` files. According to this post [About AMR audio file playing issue on different devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758167/about-amr-audio-file-playing-issue-on-different-devices) iOS4.3 above does not support `AMR` ,but how can mail app can play `AMR` files?

I tried converting `AMR` to `caf` file using `ExtAudioFile` ,but I am getting an error code 1718449215 which I found out that it means `kAudioFormatUnsupportedDataFormatError`.

Comment: If you have any update please update here.

Answer (score 1):

Even it is an old question, I still do not have an answer.

Instead, my way is converting to wave in advance, with the use of the following library from Github

https://github.com/justinjing/RecordWAVToAMRDemo/blob/master/AmrConvertAndRecord/VoiceConvert/VoiceConverter.mm